# Load times of S3 Static Website

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-s3

We have recently decided to move our static single page website to AWS S3, the previous server was hosted by Godaddy(cpanel) in singapore. We are using Synthetics New Relic to monitor our website and what comes is unexpected. I maybe be misreading the graphs.

- I was expecting the load time for US and Europe to decrease and all other servers to increase but only Ireland is working well with load times less than[image: Load Times]
- Why the average load times increase?
- Why does the graph fluctuates so much? New Relic docs point out that this should be stable for static site.
- What is average load size and how it decreased?
- How can I improve it! what other stats can help me diagnose the issue?
- Could DNS be an issue, I changed Name Servers 20hrs ago.
- Could this be because Godaddy is forwarding to Route53?

UPDATE:

After Using CloudFront

[image: Improved Load Times Using CloudFront]
[image: Average Page Load Time Distribution]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use S3 directly. You should put the S3 bucket behind CloudFront for best performance.

Comment: But still the behaviour is unexpected? Latencies from someplace should increase and decrease from other places? Can u point the reasons of why do you say that? Or point me some other place to read it!

Comment: S3 is a storage engine. It is optimized for storing data. While it can make that data available via Internet public URLs, it is still a storage engine. Latency is expected and from experience it is normal to have variable latency when getting objects from S3, I am not sure if its geographically related or not. CloudFront will cache the objects from S3 and it is optimized for very fast delivery of static content over the Internet.

Comment: What I could deduce was that the go daddy server had a cache i.e apache. Whereas S3 dosent have caches.